# More problems: .remove works first time, but not again

Tags: javascript, raphael

In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/BjMzH/) code.

I have something wrong with the 'changeOrb' section, as doing the same steps 'by hand' results in the correct output.

In other words, if i clearOrb, then drawOrb as two steps it works, but the changeStatus function causes two 'Orbs' in the same div.

Comment: What's the point of all the `(function() {...})()` in your code? You're not making any practical use of them.

Comment: My browser Chrome version 15..0.874 displays the correct behavior => the blue orbs replace the previous ones.

Comment: the (function() {...})()); was to allow the objects to be manipulated at the global level, I thought. I want to be able to create multiple of these and other objects, and change them independently

Comment: @user1318036: The function *prevents* variables from being global. It just happens that you haven't made any variable declarations in those functions. The variables you've assigned don't have use `var`, so they're implicit globals. If you get rid of those immediately invoked functions, your code will be no different.

Comment: I apparently mis-lead myself. Thanks for the correction. However, after cleaning up the functions, I have the same issue. I see this with Safari, Firefox (on Mac), and IE 8...

Comment: You could probably fix it by changing your changeOrb functions to use child1 and child2 instead of 'child1' and 'child2'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THis is not the `.remove()`function that doesn't work, but the way your handle your variables `child1` and `child2`.

I change a bit the flow and it works. Please have a look

http://jsfiddle.net/BjMzH/25/